# Should I use returning functions when the return value isn't needed?

Tags: c++, function, return-type

I have a function that looks like this:

```
int Game::GetInput() {
    while (true) {
        // do stuff
        if (something) {
            // do this
            return 0;
        }

        else {
            // do other stuff
        }
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if it is common or proper to have a returning function, rather than a void function, for the sole purpose of leaving the function (the value being returned wouldn't do anything in the program except for ending the function). Is this good practice, or is there a better way to end a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make your function `void`, and simply `return`?

```
// vv void return type
void Game::GetInput() {
    while (true) {
        // do stuff
        if (something) {
            // do this
            return;  // <<<< No return value
        }

        else {
            // do other stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @vorbis: Yes.  A `void` return type indicates that there is no value to be returned.

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem with void functions. If it does not return anything useful, it should be void.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily just use `return;` with no parameter to exit a `void` function. Your above code would become:

```
void Game::GetInput() {
    while (true) {
        // do stuff
        if (something) {
            // do this
            return;
        }

        else {
            // do other stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no useful value for the function to return, it is better not to return a value - because the calling code should check the returned value.

Your code can be doubly simplified:

```
void Game::GetInput() {
    while (true) {
        // do stuff
        if (something) {
            // do this
            return;
        }
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```

The `else` is unnecessary; the only way to execute the *'do other stuff'* is if `something` is false.